# Are there any mathematic rules for double series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a courses called Information transmission and processing. We saw a formula to compute the mutual information of two symbols, but we didn't see the math behind it. The formula is : $$H(s_2|s_1) = − \sum_{s_1=1}^n \sum_{s_2=1}^n p(s_1) · p(s_2|s_1) · log_2 p(s_2|s_1)$$

where $s_i$ is a specific symbol and $p(s_i)$ is this symbol's change to perform.

I want to factor this equation (separate the two summations), but I don't know if there are certain rules to deal with double series?

Comment: I doubt you will do much better than $\displaystyle − \sum_{s_1=1}^n p(s_1) · \left(\sum_{s_2=1}^n p(s_2|s_1) · log_2 p(s_2|s_1)\right)$

Comment: could change to products with the $\log_2$, suppose that's not what you're looking for though..